# Encrypted home folder gets unmounted just like that

Tags: 20.04, home-directory, ecryptfs

Since yesterday I have encountered something rather odd *twice* in what is a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 installation (i.e. not upgraded from an older version). The machine is just used by me and there is no indication anyone from the outside could have gotten in.

The mount of the encrypted home folder just disappears without *any* indication as to why or how. The symptoms are that in the terminal emulator I only see a handful of folders and that README telling me to use `ecryptfs-mount-private`. If I have other programs open which require files from my home folder, they start misbehaving. Browser extensions "disappear" (clicking the respective buttons brings up the usual window, just smaller and saying "file not found"). Also in my Chromium-based browser I received a prompt telling me that an application wants to create a keyring named "Default Keyring" (however, dismissing that and looking through Seahorse all looks perfectly fine).

I'm puzzled what causes this.

The first time around I was actively using the machine, just not in my home folder at the time. I noticed when I wanted to copy something *out* of my home folder that it was gone. I then logged off and back in. The second time around I had locked the machine and when I returned in the morning, the encrypted home folder was unmounted.

**Q:** What causes this? How do I prevent the encrypted home folder from being unmounted while the machine is in use?

---

Using `ecryptfs-mount-private` I *can* mount the encrypted home folder again (just have to `cd $(pwd)` for anything running inside `~myuser`). So the problem is *not* that I can't back in, the problem is that it gets unmounted for seemingly no reason and there is no indication other than misbehaving applications.